# Usage of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. Please Advise

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, express-edition

I'd like you all to give me hints and advise on the following scenario:

We are considering using Microsoft's SQL Server 2008 R2 Express for a business Web Application.

The Web Application won't have more than 10 CRUDs, and won't have a high data traffic, all of them are simple web forms. About data scalability, the Web Application is basically focused on employee data, like personal information, vacancy control, and the daily frequency control.

From what I've seen, I've estimated a maximum of 5 simultaneous users, generating data traffic.

And also, our employee table should hold a maximum of 100 records.

As to physical limitations I think we're fine, since I don't think a maximum of 100 employee should generate 10 GB for the next, say, ten years? But since I've read that the Express edition only manages 1 GB of RAM and uses only 1 CPU, I thought it'd be best to ask.

Do you think it can manage to keep up a good response and performance in this case?

So please advise on using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express or some other database manager. Just keep in mind that it has to be free.

Aditional info:

- Windows Server 2008;
- 4 GB of RAM;
- 1 TB HD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That currently sounds perfectly sufficient. Check out the limitations of the Express version so you know if/when you'll reach a point where you'll need to seek out a more encompassing version.

Answer (score 7):

I believe Express should be more than adequate. Once your database is larger than 1GB it won't all fit in memory, but unless your hard drive is 5400 RPM and your users are very particular it is quite unlikely they would ever know the difference. It doesn't sound like you'll get past 1GB in any feasible time frame anyway...

Answer (score 5):

To be blunt, my HTC phone would run that load. Whilst playing Angry Birds.

I wouldn't worry about Express edition of SQL Server